# How to backup Azure VM in Resource Group?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Is is possible to backup or take a snapshot of a VM created with the Azure preview portal in a Resource Group (not classic/CloudService-based ones)?
These new VMs are not visible from the old portal, so I cannot use Azure Backup, and the VM blade does not show any option to capture it/take a snapshot.

Comment: This question belongs on ServerFault. It's not a programming question.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [How to backup Azure VM in a Resource Group?](https://serverfault.com/questions/713742/how-to-backup-azure-vm-in-a-resource-group)